# $L^p$ estimates and functions with positive Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

For $f\in\mathcal{S}$ a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $m$ a bounded function, define $Tf$ by $\widehat{T f}=m\cdot \widehat{f}$.

Fix $1<p<\infty$, $p\not=2$. Suppose we have proved that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$ \|Tf\|_p \le C \|f\|_p$$
holds for all $f\in\mathcal{S}$ satisfying $\widehat{f}\ge 0$.

Is it still possible that $T$ is not $L^p\to L^p$ bounded?

I believe that the answer is yes, but I don't know of an example. I'd also be grateful for any reference where this or similar situations (possibly in the context of other kinds of operators) are discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize for answering my own question (and for asking a trivial question).
The answer is yes. If $\widehat {f}\ge 0$, then we always have by the triangle inequality,
$$\|Tf\|_4=\|\widehat{Tf}*\widehat{Tf}\|_2^{1/2}\le C \|\widehat{f}*\widehat{f}\|_2^{1/2}=C\|f\|_4 $$
so any multiplier that is not bounded on $L^4$ is a counterexample.